# Are bi-Lipschitz functions on $\mathbb{R}^d$ homeomorphisms?

Tags: general-topology, lipschitz-functions

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^d\to\mathbb{R}^d$ be bi-Lipschitz, that is, there is $C>0$ such that
$$
C^{-1} |x-y| \le |f(x)-f(y)| \le C |x-y| 
$$
for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^d$.

Is $f$ automatically surjective (and therefore a homeomorphism of $\mathbb{R}^d$)? This is easily seen to be true for $d=1$, and appears to be true in any dimension, but I can't find a proof.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bi-Lipschitz maps preserve Cauchy sequences and converging sequences, both ways. Hence, they 
preserve completeness. It follows that $f(\mathbb{R}^d)$ is complete in the restriction metric, hence is a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}^d$.

On the other hand, $f(\mathbb{R}^d)$  is open by the [invariance of domain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariance_of_domain).