# Double Lipschitz condition?

Tags: inequality, convex-optimization, quadratic-forms, lipschitz-functions

Is there any particular name for this condition: $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ such that
$$L_1\Vert x-y \Vert\le\Vert f(x)-f(y)\Vert\le L_2\Vert x-y \Vert$$
for all different and nonzero vectors $x,y\in \mathbb{R}^n$, with $L_1\in\mathbb{R}$, $L_1<L_2$, and $L_2>0$

I know that the upper-bound is the Lipschitz condition, but what about the lower bound?

Any idea of which class of functions satisfies this inequality? I am not sure if a function $f(\cdot)$ with lower and upper bounded Jacobian satisfies this condition.

Comment: Presumably $L_1 >0$.

Comment: $L_1$ can be either positive or negative, but $L_1<L_2$. I just included this in the question.

Comment: @Dan if $L_1$ is negative then the inequality is trivial...

Comment: It would mean that $f$ is injective and is invertible on its range with Lipschitz constant ${1 \over L_1}$.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1202739/27978