# Is a continuously differentiable bi-Lipschitz map on $\mathbf R^d$ a $C^1$-diffeomorphism?

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, differential-geometry, lipschitz-functions, inverse-function-theorem

> **Question:** Let $f:\mathbf R^d\to \mathbf R^d$ be a continuously  differentiable map. Suppose that $f$ is [bi-Lipschitz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipschitz_continuity), that is, there exist a constant $C>1$, such that
>   $$C^{-1}|x-y|\le |f(x)-f(y)| \le C|x-y|, \quad \forall x\in\mathbf R^d.$$
>   Is $f$ a [$C^1$-diffeomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffeomorphism)?

---

What I know is that $f:\mathbf R^d\to \mathbf R^d$ is bijective (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1202739/are-bi-lipschitz-functions-on-mathbbrd-homeomorphisms)), and then it is a Lipchitz homeomorphism whose inverse is also Lipschitz. But how to show the differentiability of the inverse $f^{-1}$?

Another way is using the [inverse function theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem),
in order to prove that $f$ is $C^1$-diffeomorphism, we need to show that the Jacobian determinant of $f$ is nowhere vanishing, i.e.,
$$\det(\nabla f(x))\ne0, \quad \forall x\in\mathbf R^d.$$
But I really don't know how to show this...

---

Now I even suspect that $f$ is not a $C^1$-diffeomorphism, but I can't find out any counterexample...

Could anyone give some hints or comments... TIA!

Comment: I believe the result follows from https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2011/09/12/the-inverse-function-theorem-for-everywhere-differentiable-maps/. I missed the missing continuity of $f$ when I wrote my answer.

Comment: I doubt that you can show that $f$ is $C^1$. I would guess differentiable is the best you can do.

Comment: @copper.hat Oh, I'm sorry... I just missed the continuous differentiability of $f$. Now I add it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that ${f(x+th)-f(x) \over t} \to {\partial f(x) \over \partial x} h$, and
hence $\| {\partial f(x) \over \partial x} h \| \ge {1 \over C} \|h\|$ and hence
the derivative is invertible.

We can use the inverse function theorem to conclude that the inverse is $C^1$.

Comment: Oops, missed the fact that $f$ is just differentiable.